# How to iterate through each line of a file and match each line of that file with all lines of the second file?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two tab delimitated files like this:
file1 whith 27,000 lines:

```
0.914482257 chr3    57757816    57757817
0.017355388 chr7    15686237    15686238
0.065539061 chr2    176164345   176164346
2E-05   chr7    149125745   149125746
0.018839033 chr11   94129428    94129429
0.982994402 chr14   93347431    93347432
0.030423226 chr4    38665152    38665153
0.781155125 chr19   12668552    12668553
0.053964176 chr9    71911350    71911351
0.732991838 chr10   103193851   103193852
0.028711544 chr19   55408468    55408469
0.74423941  chr18   44701798    44701799
```

file2 whith 70,0000,000 lines:

```
chr3    57757810    57757819    1   59  48  0.814   ATGGCCGGTGT
chr1    11780   11780   1   103 99  0.961   GACTGCGCAAA
chr4    38665151    38665153    1   58  52  0.897   TTTGCCGGATT
chr1    11826   11826   1   75  55  0.733   TTAAACGAGAT
chr1    11841   11841   1   22  13  0.591   AGCACCGGGTA
chr1    12520   12520   1   66  31  0.470   AGAGCCGCAGG
chr1    12557   12557   1   50  41  0.820   TAGAACGGAGC
chr10   103193851   103193852   1   96  31  0.323   TCCCACGAAGG
chr18   44701798    44701799    1   53  35  0.660   ACACCCGGCAC
```

I want to merge these two files if the second column of file1==first column of file2 and the third and forth columns of file1 be equal or between the values of the second and third column of file2; and output columns 1,2, and 3 of file1 and 6 of file2.
Output like this:

```
chr3    57757816    57757817    0.914482257 0.814
chr4    38665152    38665153    0.030423226 0.897
chr10   103193851   103193852   0.732991838 0.323
chr18   44701798    44701799    0.74423941  0.660
```

I wrote this nested for loop by it does not give me the output I want:

```
f=open("file1.txt")
g=open("file2.txt")
for i in g:
    i = i.rstrip().split("\t")
    for j in f:
        j=j.rstrip().split("\t")
        if int(j[2])>=int(i[1]) and int(j[3])<=int(i[2]) and j[1]==i[0]:
            print(j[1], j[2], j[3], float(j[0]), float(i[6]))
```

Here is the output:

```
chr3 57757816 57757817 0.914482257 0.814
```

I add some codes to the loop to see the problem. It seems that as the loop compare the first line of the file2 with all lines of file1, it does not do the same for other lines of file2.
Here is my code for checking:

```
f=open("file1.txt")
g=open("file2.txt")
for i in g:
    i = i.rstrip().split("\t")
    print(i)
    for j in f:
        j=j.rstrip().split("\t")
        if int(j[2])>=int(i[1]) and int(j[3])<=int(i[2]) and j[1]==i[0]:
            print(j[1], j[2], j[3], float(j[0]), float(i[6]))
        else:
            print("not")
```

and here is its output.

```
['chr3', '57757810', '57757819', '1', '59', '48', '0.814', 'ATGGCCGGTGT']
chr3 57757816 57757817 0.914482257 0.814
not
not
not
not
not
not
not
not
not
not
not
['chr1', '11780', '11780', '1', '103', '99', '0.961', 'GACTGCGCAAA']
['chr4', '38665151', '38665153', '1', '58', '52', '0.897', 'TTTGCCGGATT']
['chr1', '11826', '11826', '1', '75', '55', '0.733', 'TTAAACGAGAT']
['chr1', '11841', '11841', '1', '22', '13', '0.591', 'AGCACCGGGTA']
['chr1', '12520', '12520', '1', '66', '31', '0.470', 'AGAGCCGCAGG']
['chr1', '12557', '12557', '1', '50', '41', '0.820', 'TAGAACGGAGC']
['chr10', '103193851', '103193852', '1', '96', '31', '0.323', 'TCCCACGAAGG']
['chr18', '44701798', '44701799', '1', '53', '35', '0.660', 'ACACCCGGCAC']
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Vahid.

Comment: I think you're overthinking this: put all items in the first file into a dictionary with the key equal to the string that you can match on. Then go through each line in the second file and add the additional information to that same key.

Comment: if I understand you, you mean I make, for example, chr3    57757816    57757817 as key like this chr3:57757816-57757817. Then how can I select values from the second file that 57757816 and 57757817 are between them? I think it only gives me the value equal to keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I must opened the other file that I wanted to iterate in the second loop, in the first loop:

```
g=open("file2.txt")
for i in g:
    i = i.rstrip().split("\t")
    with open("file1.txt") as f:
        for j in f:
            j=j.rstrip().split("\t")
            if int(j[2])>=int(i[1]) and int(j[3])<=int(i[2]) and j[1]==i[0]:
                print(j[1], j[2], j[3], float(j[0]), float(i[6]))
```

Here is output:

```
chr3 57757816 57757817 0.914482257 0.814
chr4 38665152 38665153 0.030423226 0.897
chr10 103193851 103193852 0.732991838 0.323
chr18 44701798 44701799 0.74423941 0.66
```